# finding the min string in an array of chars

Tags: c, arrays, strcpy

I'm trying to find the MIN string out of a bunch of strings in a 2D array initialized with empty strings "". The user enters some strings which are then `strcpy`ied and then the following method gets called.However the if statement doesn't work as expected:

```
void determineMIN(char strings[][MAX]) {
  char minC[MAX] = "Z"; // Highest alphabetic uppercase char in ASCII(value: 090)
  int i;
  for(i=0; i < MAX; i++) {
    if((strcmp(minC,strings[i]) >= 0) && (strcmp(minC,"") != 0)) { 
      printf("called\n");
      strcpy(minC,strings[i]);
    } else { // < 0
      continue;
    }
  }
  printf("MIN: %s\n",minC);
}
```

Take this case for example: the user enters the following 3 strings `"cat"`,`"dog"` and `"sheep"` .Considering the rest of the array is filled with "" strings shouldn't my condition work? Because it doesn't it only gets called once and then minimum is set to "".

Comment: Yeah you're right about that, i forgot the ! in front of the ().I probably have another mistake somewhere in there since it prints sheep as the MIN. I'll go over it again

Comment: Change `(strcmp(minC,"") != 0)` to `(strcmp(strings[i],"") != 0)` because you want to skip if `strings[i]` is `""` not `minC`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that you skip if `minC` is equal to `""`, but you should check `strings[i]`:

```
void determineMIN(char strings[][MAX])
{
  char minC[MAX];
  int i;

  strcpy(minC, strings[0]);
  for(i=1; i < MAX; i++)
  {
    if((strcmp(strings[i],"") != 0) && (strcmp(strings[i], minC) < 0)) 
    { 
      printf("called\n");
      strcpy(minC,strings[i]);
    }
    else
    {
      continue;
    }
  }
  printf("MIN: %s\n",minC);
}
```

Comment: You are correct, sorry about those few mistakes it was stupid on my part. Thanks for helping me understand and fix my errors!